# how to mock webclient sync call in Junit5 springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-webclient

Have Used WebClient in Springboot project to call external API Synchronously, have written testcases for this application using Junit5 and Mockito, how to mock the webClient which is invoking external API in our testcases.

**springboot version : 2.7.5**

**Java : 11**

We are creating the Webclient with certificate to call external API as shown below :

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("kWebclient")
    public WebClient createWebClient() throws Exception {

        return buildSslEnabledWebClient();

    }

    private WebClient buildSslEnabledWebClient() throws Exception {

        final KeyStore trustStore = createKeyStore(trustStorePath, 
         kConfigVault.getKTrustStorePassword());

        try {

            final TrustManagerFactory trustManager = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManager.init(trustStore);

            final SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(trustManager).build();

            final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(ssl -> {
                ssl.sslContext(sslContext);
            });
            final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
            final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                    .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size)).build();

            return WebClient.builder().exchangeStrategies(strategies)
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | SSLException e) {
            log.error("Could not initialize Webclient with the trustore data", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**Attaching the testcase sample am trying , where am getting null for all autowired in strategy class :**

```
//also tried : @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)/@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
and @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)


@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = { Cicrawlrequesttrigger.class })
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class StrategyTest {
  @Autowired //tried @InjectMocks
    private StockAvailibilityStrategy stockAvailibilityStrategy;
    @Autowired  //also tried @Mock and @MockBean
    @Qualifier("kWebclient")
    private WebClient kWebclient;

@BeforeEach
    public void beforEach() {
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
}


@Test
    void testStrategyOptimise() {
        CentralRepoLite central = getCentralRepoLite();
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(
                "[{response}]",
                HttpStatus.OK);

        Mockito.lenient().when(Strategy.invokLoc(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(),
                Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        CReady cy = setTestCReady();
        strategy.optimise(testCRequest, StoreInfo, centralRepoEntities,
                cRepo, executor);
        assertNotNull(cy);
 }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck doing this? You can mock `WebClient` just as you would any class.

Comment: Hi @tgdavies , thankyou verymuch for your response , am getting null for the kWebclient while calling the api for that testcase, however i have created mock bean in testcase , attached the testcase sample

Comment: You will need to edit your question to include a complete, minimal, runnable example which reproduces the problem. At present your question is not answerable. You seem to have a clas which includes an @bean and an @BeforeEach annotation, and a test which doesn't show how the class you are testing is created. You say that `kWebClient` is null, but don't mock or inject a WebClient. I'm sorry, but your question is incoherent.

Comment: Hi @tgdavies , updated the question with working code, issue is am getting null for all the autowired instance and variables loaded from property file, could you please check and help